# At which point in the lifetime of a UICollectionViewController will visibleCells be populated

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, uicollectionview

I need to access the visible cells of a UICollectionViewCollectionViewControllers's UICollectionView so I need to know when the visible cells can be accessed.

Example:

```
let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("foo") as UICollectionViewController
self.addChildViewController(vc)
self.view.addSubview(vc.view)

//prints out 0
println("visibleCells: \(vc.collectionView!.visibleCells().count)")
```

Comment: They should be visible in `viewDidAppear`. But you probably shouldn't access them that way. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I need to access the visible cells during a custom transition